# Best way to get the pathname from string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I am trying to get the first segment of the path from a string.

**Current Behaviour:**

```js
const pathOne = '/tasks/123456789';
const pathTwo = '/tasks';
const pathThree = '/tasks?name=Doe';

const resultOne = pathOne.split('/')[1];
const resultTwo = pathTwo.split('/')[1];
const resultThree = pathThree.split('/')[1];

console.log(resultOne, resultTwo, resultThree);
```

As you see in the above code, I tried split the string and get second element from the array which has the first segment of the path.

But unfortunately in the last one, I get query params along with it, which I intend to remove it and get only `tasks` for **all three** strings.

Kindly please help me with *efficient way* of achieving the result that gives only the first segment of the path and **ignore** query params.

**Note:**
Please don't consider it as url and it is just a normal string with pathname and I am intend to get only the first segment of it `tasks` .

Comment: maybe this could be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: @DiegoDeVita, The given link is about url. This is not exactly complete url. Instead just a part of url and is a string type.

Comment: Pass the current origin as a base, and then `.pathname` will give you what you want.

Comment: `o = new URL( '/path/to?test=asdf', 'http://example.com').pathname` //I still consider this better than using your own parser.. unless it was for the sake of implementing an algorithm as an excercise

Comment: What does it matter if the intermediary steps treat the string as a relative URL in order to extract parts if the result is what you want? If this is an academic exercise, please state so clearly in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do somethong like this

```js
const pathOne = '/tasks/123456789';
const pathTwo = '/tasks';
const pathThree = '/tasks?name=Doe';

const getFile = fullPath => {
const [path, query] = fullPath.split('?')
 return path.split('/')[1]
}



console.log(getFile(pathOne));
console.log(getFile(pathTwo));
console.log(getFile(pathThree));
```

Comment: Here first one gives `123456789` **instead** of `tasks` which is not the expected.

Comment: @HelloWorld you're right! I thought the OP wanted  the last portion of the path

Comment: What about `/tasks#some-fragment`?

Comment: @R4ncid, I am the OP btw :). I am able to manage with your solution thanks.

Comment: @HelloWorld I'm glad you did :)

Comment: the path may include further `?` and this parser will fail. Despite those being very odd values it's still considered valid. that's a reason why I didn't agree with this strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You have index key after .split() -> [1]. When you have key index, you told "Give me first separated word from string"
If you remove it, you can get every string separated by "/". Try :)

```
const pathOne = '/tasks/123456789';
const pathTwo = '/tasks';
const pathThree = '/tasks?name=Doe';

const resultOne = pathOne.split('/');
const resultTwo = pathTwo.split('/');
const resultThree = pathThree.split('/');

console.log(resultOne, resultTwo, resultThree);
```

EDIT: IF you don't wanna query parameters, you must split "pathThree" string also by "?"

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the string from the `window` object you can obtain the [pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) from the `window.location` property

```
const pathParts = window.location.pathname.split('/');
```

Otherwise you can construct an [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object

```
const myUrl = new URL('https://www.example.com/get/the/pathname?param=1&param=2');
const pathParts = myUrl.pathname.split('/');
```

If you're working on a path string (not a valid url) I'd suggest something like

```
const myStr = '/get/the/pathname?paramA=1&paramB=2';
const parts = myStr.split('?')[0].split('/');
```

Comment: No I am not getting string from url object. It is just a string that I get from Backend api.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code hereconst pathOne = '/tasks/123456789';
const pathTwo = '/tasks';
const pathThree = '/tasks?name=Doe';

const resultOne = pathOne.split('/')[1];
const resultTwo = pathTwo.split('/')[1];
const resultThree = pathThree.split(/[/?_]+/)[1];

console.log(resultOne, resultTwo, resultThree);
```

Comment: Change the split condition to const resultThree = pathThree.split(/[/?_]+/)[1];

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).